# Rank-order response carry-forward with images (Qualtrics)

Tags: javascript, ranking, qualtrics

I'm about to conduct a survey using Qualtrics for my thesis; which requires me to measure choice-induced attitude change using an initial ranking task, followed by a choice task with responses tailored for each participant according to their responses from the ranking task (let's say comparing the options they ranked 'fourth and fifth'), and then the same ranking task again.

I've been having a small problem with it, as Qualtrics doesn't let me impose the correct criteria on 'carry-forward responses' option (needs a little JavaScript code to be embedded into the choice question, apparently). Indeed I found a webpage with instructions on how to do the exact thing: http://kurtmunz.com/2015/05/28/rank-order-carry-forward-in-qualtrics-with-javascript/

Following this logic was partially successful, because it only displays the text associated with selected options, but not the images of the said options, unfortunately. Since displaying the images is critical to my experimental setup, I need to find a solution and I guess the code given in the link just isn't written with the whole image thing in mind.

I was wondering if anybody has faced the same problem and/or has a solution to this.

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I'd suggest you contact Qualitrics for support. I don't think SO is necessarily the best place to get an answer.

Comment: How did you add the images to your original question..Qualtrics insert graphic or adding html to the choice text?

Comment: I did it through "insert graphic" - should I try doing it through HTML?

Comment: by the way, I have been in touch with Qualtrics customer support many times (tried to do it through a couple different algorithms), but I was told that this is not doable within the existing capabilities of it, and they do not give assistance about JavaScript modifications...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using insert image, try adding the images to the choices using html. I think the html will become part of the piped choice text. For example:

```
Choice text<br><img src='xxx' alt='yyy'>
```

Change the JavaScript to use double quotes around the piped fields.

Personally, I prefer to use a web service to sort and return rankings.